# WebResource is not working on the host

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webresource

I have a class library project which contains a java script file "libscript.js" which is located in the `library/Resources/Scripts` folder.

I marked "libscript.js" file as an Embedded Resource from property window.

I also added the following line of code to assemblyInfo.cs:

```
[assembly: WebResource("Library.Resources.Scripts.libscript.js", "text/javascript")]
```

Finally, I referenced the library in my website project.

When I run the project on local machine, it works fine and javascript file was loaded correctly. Also when I create an application in IIS, it works fine.

But when i upload the project to the host, the script file is not loaded and not found!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have done are steps 1 (embed the js as a resource) and 2 (add the webresource to assembly.cs) out of 3.

The third step is to extract the js and send it to the browser:

```
  protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
  {
    base.OnInit(e);

    this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude(
       this.GetType(), "libscript", 
       Page.ClientScript.GetWebResourceUrl(this.GetType(), 
       "Library.Resources.Scripts.libscript.js"));
  }
```

You also need to modify the webresource definition in assembly.cs to include the [PerformSubstitution](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webresourceattribute.performsubstitution.aspx) parameter so that the correct path to the js is generated:

```
[assembly: WebResource("Library.Resources.Scripts.libscript.js", "text/javascript", PerformSubstitution = true)]
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. i also added the step 3 in my code but i forget to add it to my question.but by adding the PerformSubstitution  the problem was solved.